# Understanding "this" context in onClick handler

Tags: reactjs, onclick, this, codepen

I'm having a hard time understanding how `this` works inside an `onClick` function. I made a small `CodePen` example [here](https://codepen.io/osundal/pen/bGNwbbz).

```
const history = {
  init() {
    this.counter = 0

    return this;
  },

  increment() {
    this.counter++;
  }
}

const a = Object.create(history).init()

const MyComponent = () => {

  a.increment();

  // a's context is lost in the onClick function, how to
  // make this work?

  return (
    <>

      <button onClick={a.increment}>
        click to increment
      </button>
    <p>{a.counter}</p>
      </>
  )
}
```

I realize `this` context is call-site specific, and it rebinds to the `onClick` function and thus the context i need to make it work is lost. But i don't know how to fix that. I realize i could use `lambda` syntax or refactor the object another way that avoids `this` completely, but that would just be dodging the problem.

Anyone able to provide a solution and a quick answer of what is really going on?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: "would just be dodging the problem" no it is not. You need to create a new function that is binded to the context you want. When and how exactly to do it is up to you.

Comment: Also you are creating a new instance of `a` on every call. Not to say that mutating some external object wont cause your component to rerender. So even if you fix the context issue your code wont update counter value on a screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set value of `this` inside increment function using `bind` function. You also need to update state of the component to re-render it.

**Code**

```
const history = {
  init() {
    this.counter = 0;
    return this;
  }, 

  increment(setCounter) {
    setCounter(++this.counter);
  }
}

const a = Object.create(history).init();

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(a.counter);  

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={a.increment.bind(a, setCounter)}>
        click to increment
      </button>
      <p>{a.counter}</p>
    </>
  )
};
```

See [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jkjlkv)